# Console.WriteLine(ArrayList) wrong output

Tags: c#, arraylist, console.writeline

I'm trying to print the content of the ArrayList of the various foreach loops but the only thing i get is the String + System.Collections.ArrayList.

For example the following code:

```
ArrayList nodeList = new ArrayList();
foreach (EA.Element element in elementsCol)
{
    if ((element.Type == "Class") || (element.Type == "Component") || (element.Type == "Package"))
    {
         nodeList.Add(element);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The nodes of MDG are:" + nodeList); //stampato a schermo la lista dei nodi nel MDG finale
```

And the output that i get is:

`The nodes of MDG are:System.Collections.ArrayList`

Can please someone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to loop through the arraylist to get its value...

```
foreach(var item in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The nodes of MDG are:" + item);
}
```

This will work..

Updated:

Use element instead of nodelist

```
Console.WriteLine("The nodes of MDG are:" + element);
```

Comment: You want to print `The nodes of MDG are:` for reach item?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(arrayList1);` does not work and that seems to be what you are suggesting, with your odd update. It  will just print the type. And putting Console.WriteLine(arrayList1)  in loop is even more ridiculous it will just repeatedly display the type. I suppose your first paragraph with the code was ok, but the rest makes no sense.

Answer (score 7):

The conversion to string for `nodeList` will just call `nodeList.ToString()` which produces the output you see. Instead you have to iterate over the array and print each individual item.

Alternatively you can use `string.Join`:

```
Console.WriteLine("The nodes of MDG are:" + string.Join(",", nodeList));
```

By the way there is no reason (or excuse) to still use `ArrayList` in C# 2 and above - if you are not maintaining legacy code switch to `List<T>`

Comment: I tried this method and doesn't work, i get "System.__ComObject" for every element in my array. How can i get the values that i have in my array and not the type of the value?

Comment: @Defi: In this case the items in the list do not have a "user friendly" `ToString()` implementation. Use a `foreach` loop and write out the properties you want specifically.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there's no good reason to use ArrayList in C#. You should *at least* use `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` instead, and even here they may be a more specific data structure available. *Never* use an untyped collection like ArrayList.

Second, when you pass an object to Console.Writeline(), it just calls the .ToString() method of the object.

**ArrayList does not override the .ToString() method inherited from the base object type.**

The .ToString() implementation on the basic object type simply prints out the type of the object.  Therefore, the behavior you posted is exactly what is expected.

I don't know the reasoning behind the choice not to override .ToString() for arrays and other sequence types, but the simple fact is that if you want this to print out the individual items in the array, you must write the code to iterate over the items and print them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (EA.Element element in elementsCol)
{
    if ((element.Type == "Class") || (element.Type == "Component") || (element.Type == "Package"))
    {
        builder.AppendLine(element.ToString());

    }
 }
 Console.WriteLine("The nodes of MDG are:" + builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This calls on nodeList.ToString(). It would make more sense to run ToString() on each element in the list and join them together:

```
Console.WriteLine("The nodes of MDG are:" + string.Join(", ", nodeList));
```

Comment: Not in 4.0. 4.0 has an IEnumerable overload. :-)

Comment: Ah it's about time they did that.  I need to get up to date with 4.0

Comment: Absolutely. But to correct: there is an IEnumerable<T> overload, not IEnumerable. So the ArrayList will be considered just another object in the context, and the return value of string.Join(", ", nodeList) would be "System.Collections.ArrayList". I guess the ToArray is needed after all. Or, preferrably, switch to List<T>.

Comment: this  `string.Join(", ", nodeList)` is not working, it just displays `System.Collections.ArrayList`

Comment: still the wrong output is showing using this method also

Answer (score 0):

I got the output that i wanted with the following code:

```
using System.IO

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\out.txt"))
        {
            Console.SetOut(writer);
         }

Console.WriteLine("the components are:");
        foreach (String compName in componentsList)
        { Console.WriteLine(compName); }
```

where componentsList is my arraylist that i wanted to print.

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.join, while coping the ArrayList to a new regular array by doing this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nodeList.ToArray()));
```