# Setting center of circle as value of point class

Tags: c#, class, geometry, point

I need to make class Circle with center defined as Point type, but I don't have a concept how to set center values, show them (write in console every circle data) and next do with them whatever I like.

I have something like this:

```
namespace Circle
{
    class Program
    {
        class Point
        {
            private float x, y;

            public Point()
            {
                x = 3.14f;
                y = 3.14f;
            }

            public Point(float a, float b)
            {
                x = a;
                y = b;
            }

            public float X
            {
                get { return x; }
                set { x = value; }
            }

            public float Y
            {
                get { return y; }
                set { y = value; }
            }

            public void Show()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("X = {0}, Y = {1}", x, y);
            }
        }

        class Circle
        {
            private Point center;
            private float radius;

            public Circle(Point s = null, float r = 1)
            {
                if (s == null) center = new Point(0,0);
                radius = r;
            }

            public float Ra
            {
                get { return radius; }
                set { radius = value; }
            }

            public Point Ce
            {
                get { return center; }
                set { center = value; }
            }

        }

            static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point p;
            p = new Point();
            p.X = 1;
            p.Y = 1;

            Circle k;
            k = new Circle();
            k.Ce = p;
            k.Ra = 19;
            Console.WriteLine("center = {0}, radius = {1}", k.Ce, k.Ra);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

For now program compile but shows weird stuff ( Center = Circle.Program+Point ).

PS. I need to keep `private float x, y;` in class `Point` as `private`.

Comment: "shows weird stuff" is not a good example of actual output. I suspect that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624872/console-writelinearraylist-wrong-output (or any other "why WriteLine prints class name in C#" post) is what you are looking for... But without good example of expected and actual output it is hard to say

Comment: What weird stuff does it show?

Comment: "Weird stuff" edited ( to Center = Circle.Program+Point ). I thought that maybe I'm doing something wrong with assigning at `k.Ce = p` or maybe I should do something to work this like that `Circle(p,19)`
`foreach` doesn't work -> `foreach (var item in k)` -  `Circle.Program.Circle does not contain public definition for GetEnumerator`

Answer (score 0):

The object property that you're trying to output is:

> k.Ce

This property has the type Point, and since .ToString() has not been implemeted yet the output will be *weird*, try implementing ToString into your **Point** class like so:

```
    public override string ToString() {
        return "X =" + x + ", Y = " + y;
    }
```

The result will be much readable now.